# Unable to open secure HTTPS websites on the tablet Android

Tags: connection-issues, https, dhcp

My laptop and tablet are connected to the same access point. The LAN port of the WiFi point is connected to the router that uses DHCP protocol. I can access all the websites including secure ones without any problem using my laptop. With the tablet, I'm not able to access HTTPS websites, my Google account, and the Google Play market. Why does it work for the laptop, but not for the tablet? What can cause it, and how can I solve it?

My device is Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (7-Inch)

I can access HTTPS websites using other networks so it means that there is a problem with my connection.

Comment: You should describe in better detail what "have problems" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had similar issues in our office router which had expired security certificate resulting in denial of HTTPS URLs. When we updated our certificate this issue was solved.

I guess your issue should be similar. I stumbled on a [web page](http://scrollsofvipin.blogspot.in/2011/04/netgear-adsl-router-connection-issue.html) that claims the solution. But looking at the solution I very much doubt its worth.